# Java regex issue?

Tags: java, html, regex

Okay so my teacher gives an assignment to read in a couple apache web server log like this for example

```
10.10.10.10 - - [27/Sep/2016:05:22:00 +0000] "GET /1.1/friendships/list.json?user_id=123 HTTP/1.1" 500 563 19 "Twitter-iPhone/6.63 iOS/10.0.2 (Apple;iPhone7,2;;;;;1)" 177.177.177.177

10.10.10.10 - - [27/Sep/2016:05:22:08 +0000] "GET /1.1/friendships/list.json?user_id=123 HTTP/1.1" 200 563 19 "Twitter-iPhone/6.63 iOS/10.0.2 (Apple;iPhone7,2;;;;;1)" 177.177.177.177

10.10.10.10 - - [27/Sep/2016:05:22:31 +0000] "GET /1.1/friendships/list.json HTTP/1.1" 200 563 19 "Twitter-iPhone/6.63 iOS/10.0.2 (Apple;iPhone7,2;;;;;1)" 177.177.177.177

10.10.10.10 - - [27/Sep/2016:05:22:59 +0000] "GET /1.1/friendships/list.json HTTP/1.1" 200 94 6 "Twitter-iPhone/6.63 iOS/10.0.1 (Apple;iPhone7,2;;;;;1)" 177.177.177.177

10.10.10.10 - - [27/Sep/2016:05:23:01 +0000] "GET /1.1/users/show.json?include_entities=1&user_id=321 HTTP/1.1" 200 4160 51 "Twitter-iPhone/6.63 iOS/9.3.5 (Apple;iPhone7,2;;;;;0)" 177.177.177.177

10.10.10.10 - - [27/Sep/2016:22:45:33 +0000] "GET /1.1/friendships/list.json?user_id=234 HTTP/1.1" 200 563 19 "Twitter-iPhone/6.63 iOS/10.0.2 (Apple;iPhone7,2;;;;;1)" 177.177.177.177

10.10.10.10 - - [27/Sep/2016:22:45:51 +0000] "POST /1.1/friendships/create.json HTTP/1.1" 200 4193 120 "Twitter-iPhone/6.62.1 iOS/9.3.5 (Apple;iPhone7,2;;;;;0)" 177.177.177.177
```

The endpoint is the path component of the URL.
For example, `/1.1/friendships/create.json`

The success rate is the level of non-500 level response codes to total request for a given endpoint expressed as a percentage with two points after the decimal.

For example

```
10.10.10.10 - - [27/Sep/2016:05:22:31 +0000] "GET /1.1/friendships/list.json HTTP/1.1" (response code is here)200 563 19 "Twitter-iPhone/6.63 iOS/10.0.2 (Apple;iPhone7,2;;;;;1)" 177.177.177.177
```

My code should print out the following which is first sorted by time and then lexicographically like so

```
2016-09-27T05:22 /1.1/friendships/list.json 75.00

2016-09-27T05:23 /1.1/users/show.json 100.00

2016-09-27T22:45 /1.1/friendships/create.json 100.00

2016-09-27T22:45 /1.1/friendships/list.json 100.00
```

Here's my attempt:

```
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.String.format;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class JavaApplication17 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // String line = "10.10.10.10 - - [27/Sep/2016:05:22:00 +0000] \"GET /1.1/friendships/list.json?XXXXX HTTP/1.1\" 500 563 19 \"Twitter-iPhone/6.63 iOS/10.0.2 (Apple;iPhone7,2;;;;;1)\" 177.177.177.177";
        LL myLL = new LL();
        String responseCodeCopy = "";
        int responseCodeAsNumber;
        Pattern a = Pattern.compile("(\\[(?<time>.*)\\])?");
        Pattern responseCodeString = Pattern.compile("\"\\s+(?<resCode>[0-9]{0,3})\\s+");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line1;
        String myString = null;
        String newLine;

        while (((line1 = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) && (line1.length() != 0)) {
            myString = line1;
            try{
            String[] firstSplit = myString.split(" - - ");
            String rest1 = firstSplit[1];

            String time = null;
            Matcher m1 = a.matcher(rest1);
            if (m1.find()) {
                time = m1.group("time");
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
                Date d1 = null;
                d1 = sdf.parse(time);
                String timeAsString = sdf.format(d1);
                long totalTime = d1.getTime();
                String[] endPointCopy = rest1.split("\"");
                String rest2 = endPointCopy[1];
                String[] splitByQuestionMark = rest2.split("\\?");
                String[] split3 = splitByQuestionMark[0].split(" ");
                String url = split3[1];
                Matcher responseCodeMatch = responseCodeString.matcher(myString);
                if (responseCodeMatch.find()) {
                    responseCodeCopy = responseCodeMatch.group("resCode").trim();
                }
                responseCodeAsNumber = Integer.parseInt(responseCodeCopy);
                newLine = timeAsString + " " + url;

                if (responseCodeAsNumber >= 500) {
                    myLL.sortedInsert(newLine, d1, url, false);
                } else {
                    myLL.sortedInsert(newLine, d1, url, true);
                }

            }

             }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(line1);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        myLL.printList();

    }//end of main

}//end of main class

class LL {

    public Node head;

    public LL() {
        this.head = null;
    }

    public void sortedInsert(String text2, Date d, String text3, boolean isHit) {

        Node temp = this.head;
        Node prev = null;
        long totalTimeCopy = d.getTime();

        while ((temp != null) && (temp.compare(totalTimeCopy, text3) < 0)) {
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp.next;
        }

        if (temp != null) {

            if (prev != null) {
                if (temp.compare(totalTimeCopy, text3) == 0) {

                    if (isHit) {
                        temp.incrementHit();
                    } else {
                        temp.incrementMiss();
                    }

                } else {
                    Node nnode;
                    if (isHit) {
                        nnode = new Node(text2, d, 1, 0, null);
                    } else {
                        nnode = new Node(text2, d, 0, 1, null);
                    }
                    nnode.next = temp;
                    prev.next = nnode;

                }
            } else if (temp.compare(totalTimeCopy, text3) == 0) {

                if (isHit) {
                    temp.incrementHit();
                } else {
                    temp.incrementMiss();
                }

            } else {
                Node nnode;
                if (isHit) {
                    nnode = new Node(text2, d, 1, 0, null);
                } else {
                    nnode = new Node(text2, d, 0, 1, null);
                }

                this.head = nnode;
                nnode.next = temp;

            }

        } else {

            Node nnode;
            if (isHit) {
                nnode = new Node(text2, d, 1, 0, null);
            } else {
                nnode = new Node(text2, d, 0, 1, null);
            }
            if (prev == null) {
                this.head = nnode;
            } else {
                prev.next = nnode;
            }

        }

    }

    public void printList() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Node temp = this.head;

        while (temp != null) {

            int Hit = temp.getHit();
            int Miss = temp.getMiss();
            DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
            double sucRate = Hit * 100 / (Hit + Miss);

            System.out.println(temp.getTimetext() + " " + temp.getEndpoint() + " " + f.format(sucRate));
            temp = temp.next;
        }

    }

}// end of LL

class Node {

    private String text;
    private int Hit;
    private int Miss;
    public Node next;
    public Date date;

    public Node(String text, Date d, int Hit, int Miss, Node next) {
        this.text = text;
        this.date = d;
        this.Hit = Hit;
        this.Miss = Miss;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return this.text;
    }

    public String getEndpoint() {
       // will get url(endpoint)
        String[] splitEndPoint = this.text.split(" ");
        return splitEndPoint[1];
    }

    public long getTime() {
        return this.date.getTime();
    }

    public String getTimetext() {
        Date d = new Date(this.date.getTime());
        SimpleDateFormat print = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");
        return print.format(d);
        // return str
    }

    public int getHit() {
        return this.Hit;
    }

    public int getMiss() {
        return this.Miss;
    }

    public void incrementHit() {
        this.Hit = this.Hit + 1;
    }

    public void incrementMiss() {
        this.Miss = this.Miss + 1;
    }

    public int compare(long Time, String Text3) {
        // if other is greater then

        if (this.getTime() < Time) {
            return -1;
        }

        if (this.getTime() > Time) {
            return 1;
        }

        if (this.getTime() == Time) {

            if (this.getEndpoint().compareTo(Text3) > 0) {
                //will return positive if 
                return 1;
            }

            if (this.getEndpoint().compareTo(Text3) < 0) {
                return -1;
            }

            if (this.getEndpoint().compareTo(Text3) == 0) {
                return 0;
            }

        }

        return 0;

    }

}
```

Now my problem isn't that it doesn't work – my problem is that it doesn't work for every case, which, I guess, in the real world means it doesn't work. Can anyone look at my regex and logic and tell me why it would potentially not give the write output? I've been working on it all week, started over and everything and I'm stumped, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What cases go wrong? How they deviate from the others? That's usually a good question to start.

Comment: idk he doest tell us the wrong output his client just tells us its wrong

Comment: but my code does print out the write output from the sample that i showed

Comment: and for five other cases but there are three examples that don't work

Comment: Yes, I checked with your input and it seemed all right.

Comment: thanks i appreciate any help

Comment: Found your problem. Code is fundamentally sound. Only mistake is in casting to double after doing int division

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is not at all with how your code runs (which appears to be fine BTW), but with how you print your percentage. The entire error is here:

```
double sucRate = Hit * 100 / (Hit + Miss);
```

You are multiplying `Hit` (an `int`) by `100` (also an `int`) to get an `int`, then dividing by another `int` (Since `Hit` and `Miss` are both `int`s). The result is an `int`, which is truncated, and only then cast to a `double`. This is fine for the cases where `Hit * 100` is a multiple of `Hit + Miss`, but I bet the professor tests with some cases where it is not.

To fix the problem, do something like

```
double sucRate = Hit * 100.0 / (Hit + Miss);
```

This will make the numerator, and hence the entire fraction into a `double` and preserve the part after the decimal point. To be extra safe against future modifications, you can do something like

```
double sucRate = Hit * 100.0 / (double)(Hit + Miss);
```

Note that the following will **not** work, since it is equivalent to what you have now (i.e. cast after truncating):

```
double sucRate = (double)(Hit * 100 / (Hit + Miss));
```

Answer (score 0):

In such a fixed format it's better to match against the whole string, or at least with an anchor in the beginning or end, than to the middle, as both your patterns do. With that in mind, you can actually combine them in one:

```
Pattern full = Pattern.compile("^(\\S+\\s+){3}\\[(?<time>[^]]*)\\]\\s+\"[^\"]*\"\\s+(?<resCode>[0-9]*)\\s");
```

That is,

```
^(\S+\s+){3}\[(?<time>[^]]*)\]\s+"[^"]*"\s+(?<resCode>[0-9]*)\s
  ~~~~~~                                                        matches a string followed by whitespace
         ~~~                                                    does so three times
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                    matches anything between [...] that DOES NOT CONTAIN a ]
                              ~~~                               matches whitespace
                                 ~~~~~~~                        matches a string between precisely one pair of "..."
                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   your resCode follows, delimites by whitespace on both sides
```

Then you can drop the inner condition on `responseCodeMatch.find()` (it's flawed anyway, if it was false you'd be using an unitialized string `responseCodeCopy`) and replace `Matcher m1 = a.matcher(rest1)` by `Matcher m1 = full.matcher(myString)` (note that I'm using the whole string, leave the ignoring of the `- -` on your regex as well!).

This solves some potential problems like the possibly unitialized variable, and is generally quicker than doing two separate matches, but most importantly, does not allow some parts of your pattern match in a different place than they should. Also, it does not assume the `- -` is absolutely fixed. In my regex these are just two more fields you don't care about.

It's hard to see if this is a solution when we don't know what the fault with your client's data is. But I believe it may be. So please go ahead and give it a try.

PS. You should ignore empty lines. Currently your application stops at encountering one. The example data you gave was interleaved by blank lines, I had to take them out to reproduce your output.

PPS. You should isolate the endpoint using the regexp as well. I see no reason for restoring to `String.split` when you have all this power at hand and *you're already using it elsewhere*. It would reduce your code in the main loop to about a half. But that's a separate question. You can surely adapt this answer to do that as well.

Comment: so wait try to delete the whole if statement that corresponds to matching the response code

Comment: Just the `if` line, not the body of the condition (you can also remove the definition of the Matcher `responseCodeMatch` that's no longer needed). You'd still need to assign `responseCodeCopy = m1.group("resCode").trim();` if you still call this full pattern matcher `m1` as I do.

Comment: \\ Matcher responseCodeMatch = responseCodeString.matcher(myString);

Comment: is that line still valid

Comment: It is *valid* but if you're having the data from `m1` it's also useless at that. The results of the matcher are not examined.

Comment: so keeping it or taking it out will do nothing basically

Comment: Removing it will make your program run a bit faster.

Comment: Also: if you're going to implement my changes or anyone else's **keep a backup**. People don't want to be labelled responsible for something that was for the worse :-)

Comment: is the various splitting still valid based off of your changes

Comment: It would be better if you could share a test case that didn't work, with intended output and actual output. Or if it's confidential, make a similar data set that exhibits the same. It's hard to help without that. It may be something like the URL not always containing a `?` or so.

Comment: i think i accounted for that with this

Comment: String[] endPointCopy = rest1.split("\"");
                String rest2 = endPointCopy[1];
                String[] splitByQuestionMark = rest2.split("\\?");
                String[] split3 = splitByQuestionMark[0].split(" ");
                String url = split3[1];

Comment: You're right, I just checked there are both cases in the above. But some non-uniformity like that. Re: various splitting: yes, it is, the regexes only read your strings. The splitting is independent on matching them and does not depend on their results either.

Comment: idk what to I'm just lost as to why this is so difficult

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is not going to fix the issue OP is having.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Well, we never learnt what the problem actually was. Congrats for spotting the conversion in your answer (+1), I believe that may be what's wrong with the output. But it could also be anything else at all.

Comment: That is very true. It just looks like the OP's code is not all that wrong in other respects.